# Get message from broadcast receiver to activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I know this question has been asked many times but still i am unable to solve my problem.I want to get the OTP from the SMS in the editText of the Activity.For this i am using broadcast receiver.

Code for broadcast receiver:

```
private static final String TAG = ReceiveSms.class.getSimpleName();
    private SmsReceivedListner smsReceived = null;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    //code to get sms....

                    Log.e(TAG, "OTP received: " + verificationCode);
                    if (smsReceived != null) {
                        smsReceived.onSmsReceived(verificationCode);
                    } else {
                        if (Constants.isLoggingEnable) {
                            Logger.logError(TAG, "Sms listner is null");

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setOnSmsReceivedListener(Context context) {
        this.smsReceived = (SmsReceivedListner) context;
    }
```

Activity Code

```
public class EnterOtp extends MasterActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnTaskComplete, SmsReceivedListner {

    private static final String TAG = EnterOtp.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context context;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.otp);
        context = this;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        setUpToolbar();




        receiveSms = new ReceiveSms();
        receiveSms.setOnSmsReceivedListener(this);





    }
```

I have used interface but always i am getting it as `null`.So what can i do to get the otp.

P.S-
I dont want to start new Activity via intent because the activity is running only, so if via Intent can i pass the otp without starting new Activity and also maintaing the back stack as well?

Comment: Are you using context.registerReceiver?

Comment: Where do you instantiate the `smsReceived` object?

Comment: in my activty but still i am getting it as null

Comment: Show the complete code.

Comment: see i have updated my code

Comment: smsReceived is always null. Am I right?

Comment: ya its always null?I dnt now how to initialize the interface

Comment: The broadcasts receivers are always recreated when received. So smsReceived is always null. Where are you want to receive sms - only when Activity is running?

Answer (score 2):

If you want receive sms only when activity is running use this code:

```
private void init()
{
     receiveSms = new ReceiveSms();
     receiveSms.setOnSmsReceivedListener(this);
     registerReceiver(receiveSms, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
}
```

And remove this receiver from AndroidManifest.xml

I hope it helped you.

EDIT:

In onDestroy you must use this code:

```
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    // ...
    unregisterReceiver(receiveSms);
}
```

Comment: You are registering receiver in Activity. When Activity is closed sms won't be received. And you have always this same instance of ReceiveSms.

Comment: But the activity is opened only